# Is there a good alternative to local Oracle 11g XE to mimic Oracle in Prod?

Tags: oracle-xe

We use Oracle in our Prod environment with a lot of MVs where we pull in data from other systems to create our schema to query.

Locally we develop against Oracle 11g XE. We just download the corresponding MV tables to our local version.  Two of these tables have over 3 million records.  Once we get done applying all the indexes our users.dbf file and TableSpace exceeds the Oracle 11g XE 11 gig limit.

I'm sure a lot of people run into this.  Is there an alternative database that could mimic the Prod full version of Oracle 11g for us as a local Oracle development database?

Comment: If your requirements are outside the scale of XE, use the standard/enterprise editions - that's what they're for

Comment: Or the personal edition.  Of course, at that point, you're paying license fees.

Comment: Take a look at the [Developer License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html).  You can probably use the full version on your desktop for free.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon.
I'm going to look into the Developer License.

Comment: Well I talked with the sales team at Oracle and they say we may need an OPN license and pointed me to this link:
http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/partner-with-oracle/get-started/join-opn/index.html

But the sales team is unsure and needs to research themselves.
Can anyone shed any light on this?

If we go Silver for $500, does that come with like 5 licenses, or does each developer need their own license?
Like 5 developers X 500 = 2500.
And would that be 2500 yearly?

Comment: @Sam I bought Oracle Personal Edition from their website.  It was about $550 with $150 yearly maintenance, for one user.  That's the *worst case* price.  It wouldn't surprise me if you could get huge discounts on that.  Or possibly you may even have a named user license agreement that would make it free.  (Although I don't think they sell those anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Free "as in beer" OTN Account at http://www.oracle.com - you can also use and install any Oracle Edition for development for Free "as in beer", again. :)

Here are the links:
Oracle Database Download Landing Page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Accept their license agreement, Select the appropriate OS and click on Select all (when you arrive at the appropriate OS Landing page). Again, accept their agreement (I know, it's not intuitive).

Here's a snippet of their license agreement:
Oracle grants You a nonexclusive, nontransferable, limited license to internally use the Programs, subject to the restrictions stated in this Agreement, only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating Your application and only as long as Your application has not been used for any data processing, business, commercial, or production purposes, and not for any other purpose.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Beware, according to my research, you are only licensed to use the OTN editions for development, as long as the product you are developing has not yet been release to production! As soon as your first production version goes live, your OTN license expires; i.e. for further development of that product you will need to buy a license.